How does flare rate and attitude change with altitude during autorotation in Helicopters?
I am presently undergoing Flying Instructor Course on a Single Engine Helicopter.
I have been wondering about following queries :

How does, if it does, the flare rate and attitude change with Altitude during autorotation in Helicopters?

If I initiate an autorotation at Sea Level Helipad from 1000ft AGL vis-a-vis 5000ft AGL, will the flare rate and attitude be same in both scenarios or will it be faster and higher in the second case?


Looking forward for people to guide me in this case !
